# Convert an empty line in txt to a blank line in CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a txt file which has some blank lines. When I want to convert to csv file, I need these Blank lines to be converted to blank rows in CSV. That means wherever it sees blank lines, it should convert to black row in CSV.

My Original script is:

```
Select-String -Path $TXTFile  -Pattern 'CN=(.*?),' -AllMatches |
  Select-Object -Expand Matches |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value } | 
  select @{L="UserID"; E={$_}} |
  Export-CSV $CSVFile -noTypeInformation
```

What I tried but does not work and is wrong:

```
Select-String -Path $TXTFile  -Pattern 'CN=(.*?),' -AllMatches |
  Select-Object -Expand Matches |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value } | 
  select @{L="UserID"; E={$_}} |
  if (Get-Content $TXTFile | where {$_ = " "} ){ "`n" }
  $_ -replace '`t'
  Export-CSV $CSVFile1 -noTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `Select-String` pattern only matches non-empty lines. Change it in your first example to something like:

```
Select-String -Path $TXTFile  -Pattern '^.*(?:CN=(.*?),.*)|\s*$' -AllMatches |...
```

In order to match lines that either contain `CN=` or only contain zero or more whitespace characters